# Mysql Connector Net 6.0.4 Setup - Failed to open XML file?

Tags: mysql

Attempting to install 'MySQL Connect Net 6.0.4' on a WinXP machine for integration with Visual Studio 2008.

Near the end of the install process a error message appears that states:

'Failed to open XML file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connect Net 6.0.4\svctag.xml,system error: -2147024786'

After this message the install process fails.

What is causing this error message?

The following MySQL bug report describes the error in more detail:

[link text](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45477)

Comment: Since you using VS2008, why not try 6.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried installing on a Windows 2003 server and the same error resulted - so its probably a bug with version 6.0.4.

The workaround for now is to install 6.0.3.

6.0.3 was available by browsing to the University of Waterloo's FTP site:

[link text](ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/mysql/Downloads/Connector-Net/)

Answer (score 1):

For me using 6.0.3 is not working either.

Using 6.0.3 you will probably get the following error when creating a dataset :
"Cannot load type with name 'MySql.Data.VisualStudio.StoredProcedureColumnEnumerator'."

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I haven't done any datasets - only sql connections.  Hopefully MySQL will come out with version 6.0.5 to fix both problems (unless Sun cancels them....)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need new MySql connector 6.0.4 assemblies you can just copy them to another location before pressing the okay button on the error message. You will find the assemblies in
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.0.4\Assemblies\
Assemblies are deleted by failed installer before quitting.