# "fatal error encountered during command execution" when trying to add a view from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, ado.net, command, execution, fatal-error

I'm trying to add some tables and views from a MySQL database to a project in VS2005. After a lot of looking around I ended using the ADO.NET connector, which works pretty fine, except when trying to add a View with the Data source configuration wizard, where I get the "fatal error encountered during command execution" error message, and when I try adding one with the query builder, where it doesn't show me the name of the columns at the diagram pane.
If I add all the SELECT commands by hand, it works like a charm. Any ideas on what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like View uses variables

> To fix this add 'allow user
>   variables=true' to your connection
>   string.  In this mode it will not
>   complain when it sees @data but
>   doesn't find a parameter of that name.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40765